# knitr pandoc: "cannot produce pdf output with pdf writer"

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, knitr, pandoc

**Up front**: using `pandoc()` in knitr, it complains when trying to compile .md or .Rmd into a PDF.

I'm streamlining the process for *reproducible research*, as has been documented in many places. I'm using `pandoc` and `knitr` and producing great documents. I'm also trying to streamline for some co-workers who are not as adept with programming, yet we're trying to use similar files. There are several options for "user friendly" markdown-centric editors, and for several reasons I'm leaning on RStudio (for them, emacs/ess for me, but that's different).

My workflow: give them a markdown (.md or .Rmd) file and have them be able to make changes and optionally re-render it into a PDF. Unfortunately, RStudio does not (AFAICT) allow setting templates or other arbitrary pandoc configuration parameters (e.g., chapters, number-sections), so using `pandoc()` in R/knitr makes a lot of sense here.

Using `whitepaper.Rmd` as the input file, I run `pandoc('whitepaper.Rmd', 'pdf')` in R and immediately get:

```
> pandoc('whitepaper.Rmd', 'pdf')
executing pandoc  -t latex --standalone --smart --number-sections --template=report.tex -f markdown -t pdf -o whitepaper.pdf "whitepaper.Rmd"
pandoc.exe: cannot produce pdf output with pdf writer
Error in (function (input, format, ext, cfg)  : conversion failed
```

I explicitly have "t:latex" in my knitr-specific header, though without it, `pandoc()` is still adding "-t pdf" to the system call, something that `pandoc.exe` does not accept.

With troubleshooting, the command works just fine if I remove `'-t pdf'`, so it seems that there is nothing wrong with the input file itself:

```
> system('pandoc  -t latex --standalone --smart --number-sections --template=report.tex -f markdown -o whitepaper.pdf "whitepaper.Rmd"')
```

There have been numerous other conversations regarding this topic: [14586177](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586177/knitr-to-produce-pdf-output-file), [14508429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508429/unable-to-run-knitr-to-produce-a-pdf-output-file), [15258233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258233/using-table-caption-on-r-markdown-file-using-knitr-to-use-in-pandoc-to-convert-t), and the heavily-discussed [11025123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025123/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-pdf). They all resolve to solutions that require command-line work, extra middle-steps, external Makefiles, or `knit2pdf()` (which uses texi2pdf, not desired).

The constraints as I see them:

- operate easily within the R environment;
- take advantage of Yihui's "`<!--pandoc ... -->`" in-file configuration (which allows
  me to continue to switch arbitrarily between my templates, for one of several examples);
- preferably, execute this with a single "standardized" command (i.e., "`pandoc('whitepaper.Rmd', 'pdf')`").

... so that, once the parameters are set in-file, editing and re-rendering is relatively brain-dead.

I can patch and overwrite Yihui's `knitr:::pandoc_one()` to remove the offending addition of '-t' and format, but I wonder what side-effects that might have elsewhere. This solution isn't sustainable nor "The Right Way (tm)".

Suggestions for "Right Ways (tm)" to solve this problem? Am I missing an easy/obvious solution?

BTW: thanks, Yihui Xie, for knitr, and John MacFarlane for pandoc. Awesomeness!
(Perhaps I could submit patch suggestions to either or both to work around for my use-case, though if it's just me then it might not be worthwhile.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think all there information you need is there in `?pandoc`, which includes the example of running `system("pandoc -h")` to see possible output formats. From that you learn that

> Output formats: asciidoc, beamer, context, docbook, docx, dzslides,
>   epub, epub3,
>                   fb2, html, html5, json, latex, man, markdown, markdown_github,
>                   markdown_mmd, markdown_phpextra, markdown_strict, mediawiki,
>                   native, odt, opendocument, opml, org, pdf*, plain, revealjs,
>                   rst, rtf, s5, slideous, slidy, texinfo, textile
>                   [*for pdf output, use latex or beamer and -o FILENAME.pdf]

So basically `format = "pdf"` is invalid, you should use `pandoc("tmp.Rmd", format = "latex", ext = "pdf")` (and acutally the `ext="pdf"` part is the default, according to `?pandoc`, so all you really need is `pandoc("tmp.Rmd", "latex")`). As for why `pandoc('whitepaper.Rmd', 'pdf')` resulted in a call with `-t pdf`, well, you told it to do that in the second argument to your `pandoc()` call.

Comment: (You know, I was so busy researching all the other posts and issues and such that I overlooked the `ext` option in `?pandoc` and the example written in stark text. *sigh*. Thanks.)